# Quarkus: REST resource can't find entities created in test

Tags: kotlin, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I'm trying to create a test for a REST resource I've created with Quarkus, Panache & Kotlin. The test first writes a few entities to the database and then performs a REST call that should return these entities.

However the REST resource can't seem to find the entities. If I query the database directly in the test, the entities are there.

My code looks like this:

```
@Entity
open class TestEntity : PanacheEntity() {

    companion object : PanacheCompanion<TestEntity, Long> {

        fun createTestString(): String {
            return "Found ${TestEntity.count()} test entities: ${
                TestEntity.listAll().joinToString(", ") { it.value }
            }"
        }
    }

    @Column(nullable = false)
    lateinit var value: String

}
```

```
@Path("/test")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Transactional
class TestResource {

    @GET
    fun test() = TestEntity.createTestString()

}
```

```
@QuarkusTest
@QuarkusTestResource(H2DatabaseTestResource::class)
@TestTransaction
class TestResourceTest {

    @Test
    fun print() {
        val entity1 = TestEntity()
        entity1.value = "foo"
        entity1.persist()

        val entity2 = TestEntity()
        entity2.value = "bar"
        entity2.persist()

        println(
            "TEST: ${TestEntity.createTestString()}"
        )

        RestAssured.given()
            .`when`().get("/test")
            .then()
            .statusCode(200)
            .body(CoreMatchers.startsWith("Found 2 test entities"))
    }
}
```

The `println()` in the test prints `TEST: Found 2 test entities: foo, bar`.
But the REST call returns `Found 0 test entities:`.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: From what I see, I would suspect that the transaction is not commited before the REST-call is made. Can you try adding the test entities to the database in a `@BeforeEach`-method?

Comment: If I create the entities in a `@BeforeEach`-method, they're already missing in the `@Test`-methods `println()`. I think this is caused by `@TestTransaction`.

Comment: This behaviour is expected. You would have to remove `@TestTransaction` and add `@Transactional` to the `@BeforeEach`-method since `@TestTransaction` will rollback the changes after the (`@BeforeEach`-)method has been executed.

Comment: Alternatively, you could try using `persistAndFlush(...)` instead of `persist(...)` in the `@Test`-method

Comment: It works if I use `@Transaction` instead of `@TestTransaction`. Guess I'll have to implement my own database clean up function.